# Jquery store link into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently building a functional test and can't get the link stored correctly.

In the web console, `$(filter('a[href*="dhcp_client/1/remove"]')->eq(0)`returns a valid object. How do I get the link of it?

```
    $client = $this->myLoginAs('admin','pass!');
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/home/');
    $link = $crawler->selectLink('advanced')->link();
    $crawler = $client->click($link);
$link = $crawler->filter('a[href*="dhcp_client/1/remove"]')->eq(0)->link();

 $crawler = $client->click($link);

 $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
```

error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.
```

Comment: Q: I am curious. What framework are you using that requires -> on method calls?

Comment: Symfony2 php web framework

Answer (score 0):

There is no link method in jQuery. Just get the href attribute

E.g.

```
.attr("href")
```

Comment: Ok, made edits and running test. Will update with results.

Comment: bummer, it hated the ->attr("href"). Not sure if symfony changes things for this.

Comment: pretty sure link() in this instance should be fine, it's just saying the node list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue that resolved my conflict was the http request after clicking the link needed to follow the redirect path.

```
 $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
```